# Invalid call stack in crash dump due to mismatched/missing *system* binary file?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2005, crash-dumps, minidump

Got this callstack when I open a Windows crash dump in Visual Studio 2005:

```
>   myprog.exe!app_crash::CommonUnhandledExceptionFilter(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS * pExceptionInfo=0x0ef4f318)  Line 41  C++
    pdm.dll!513fb8e2()  
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for pdm.dll]   
    kernel32.dll!_UnhandledExceptionFilter@4()  + 0x1c7 bytes   
    ...
```

Looking at the module load info:

```
...
'DumpFM-V235_76_1_0-20110412-153403-3612-484.dmp': Loaded '*C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\pdm.dll', No matching binary found.
...
```

We see that this binary was not even loaded, because the machine used to analyze the dump is a different machine than the machine that produced the dump.

I don't have access to this other machine at the moment -- can I somehow get this stack fixed, or will I always need the exact binary at this exact path location?

Comment: Have you tried loading the dump within Windbg?

Comment: @Naveen - Haven't tried WinDBG yet. But why should there be any difference? I simply don't have this DLL at this location and it appparently is also not fetched via MS's Symbol Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely want to debug this dump in Visual Studio, then you can get away with copying the system DLLs from the machine that produced the dump **to the same folder where your .dmp file is**. That way, it will load those binaries instead of trying to find them in the same path on the debugging system as they were on the original system (which probably will contain different versions of the same modules).

As Naveen pointer out though, you won't have this problem when loading the dump in WinDBG (for reasons I have yet to understand). That is why when I get a dump from clients, I always analyze them in WinDBG.

If you need help on using WinDBG for crash dump analysis, the following Web site is full of info on the subject: http://www.dumpanalysis.org/.

Comment: "you won't have this problem when loading the dump in WinDBG" ... what exactly will WinDBG do differently? (what, not how) There's a different binary and there're no symbols available for pdm.dll on the MS symbol server. Certainly WinDBG can't do magic?

Comment: Your question was: "will I always need the exact binary at this exact path location". You did not say you did not have the binaries (.dll) or .pdbs on the debugger machine. What WinDbg does differently than VS is that from my experience, it never bugged me about missing binaries. When I had .pdb files with no .DLL file, WinDbg would still load the .pdb and do what it can with it. VS would completely refuse to load symbols, so there's not even room for trying to do anything. Of course, without binaries or pdb files, I have no suggestion.

Comment: Answer accepted. **WinDBG, unlinke VS, does not need the actual binary files**, just the dump-image and the pdb files is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [ModuleRescue](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/modulerescue.html) tool from the folks at DebugInfo.com. This will scan a dump file, allow you to choose the module that isn't loading symbols, and then it generates a fake module that has just enough info in it for the debugger to load the symbols from the symbol server.

When Visual Studio can't load the symbols for this module and opens a dialog asking you to find the symbols, just point your debugger at that fake module and it will load correctly.

This tool basically does the same thing that WinDbg does, albeit with a different workflow.

Comment: The site  DebugInfo.com is no longer available

Comment: Yes, it looks like the site is gone. You can, however, access that tool via the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20190421154620/http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/modulerescue.html